# Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am getting the following error message when trying to compile an Android app:

```
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_analytics
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-bom.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://github/com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases/com/google/firebase/firebase-bom/maven-metadata.xml.
```

From my reading, it looks like I am missing something in my implementations. I have the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
```

What else should I be adding? Is there any documentation on this that I'm just not seeing?

Also tried adding:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:16.0.0"
```

No luck.

EDIT: it seems like it might be related to this:

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                details.useVersion '12.0.1'
            }
            if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                details.useVersion '12.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
```

in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Change `firebase-core` from:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
```

into this:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7"
```

And add the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:16.0.0"
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message, after making the changes to app/build.gradle and cleaning the project

Comment: remove all three `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"` including firebase bom and then add each one alone and build to see which dependency is giving this error and tell me

Comment: @CecilRodriguez did you try the above?

Comment: I got it working - it was unrelated and in a different file where an override was taking place due to some third party library adding it

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Firebase [BoM](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v24-2-0) is `24.2.0`. While frankly speaking, why do you even need it? It's just a meta package, which bloats the APK - and delete that `configurations.all` block, too. That `BoM` dependency and the manipulation of version numbers can both be ditched.

Comment: I believe it was added by one of the packages I am using.

Comment: @CecilRodriguez I find it highly unlikely that another package would add a dependency into the `build.gradle`, while it is non-sense to bake in the whole SDK; better only select the packages which are actually required to perform the task - the rest is noise. As a meta package, the BoM has dependencies on every Firebase library, but not the other way around. And so far, I came across no realistic use case (it might only have one internally).

Comment: I think he means a react native plugin added this dependency